# How do you do a UNION inside a recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here I have a standard hierarchical table:

```
CREATE TABLE GroupMembers (
   group_id    VARCHAR,
   member_id   VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO GroupMembers VALUES
    ('1', '10'),
    ('1', '11'),
    ('10','100'),
    ('10','101'),
    ('20','200'),
    ('20','201');
```

Now to get all members of group '1' I do:

```
WITH RECURSIVE members(id) AS (
   VALUES('1')
   UNION
   SELECT gm.member_id
   FROM GroupMembers gm
   INNER JOIN members m ON gm.group_id=m.id
)
SELECT * FROM members;
```

Which yields: '1', '10', '11', '100', '101'.

Now a new wrinkle: I have aliases for ids

```
CREATE TABLE Aliases (
   member_id  VARCHAR,
   alias_id   VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO Aliases(member_id, alias_id) VALUES
    ('11', '20');
```

Now I want to get all members. Since '11' is an alias for '20', the result should be: '1', '10', '11', '100', '101', '200', and '201'.

I tried the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE members(id) AS (
   VALUES('1')
   UNION
   SELECT gm.member_id
   FROM GroupMembers gm
   INNER JOIN members m ON gm.group_id=m.id
   UNION
   SELECT a.alias_id
   FROM Aliases
   INNER JOIN members m ON gm.group_id=m.id
)
SELECT * FROM members;
```

but I get the error `circular reference: members`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE members(id) AS (
   VALUES('1')
   UNION
   SELECT groupWithAliases.member_id
   FROM 
   ( SELECT group_id, member_id FROM GroupMembers 
     UNION
     SELECT alias_id AS group_id, member_id
     FROM Aliases ) groupWithAliases
   INNER JOIN members m ON groupWithAliases.group_id=m.id
)
SELECT * FROM members;
```

Please note that I used UNION when constructed the `groupWithAliases` sub-query to eliminate duplicates

Comment: Note: the inner join with the recursive cte ("INNER JOIN members") must take place *outside* the subselect in order to avoid "recursive reference in a subquery" error.

Comment: the `INNER JOIN members` is outside. There is a UNION inside the groupWithAliases sub-query, but it does not use the members CTE, so it should work fine. Unfortunately SQL fiddle is not working for me at the moment, so I can't test it

Comment: Sorry, I intended it to be an additional note-of-interest comment based on what I ran into, not a proposed modification to your example.